# Find Differences Between Images with OpenCV Python

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv

How can I detect the differences between the 2 images below?

I have tried to threshold the 2 images and apply bitwise XOR to find the difference but still couldn't get the result that I am looking for.

Image 1

[image]

Image 2

[image]

Comment: What result are you looking for? The big differences are the areas in the centre that have been masked, but there are also more subtle ones, like the orange bits at the top of the image. Both images are also jpg and even if you resave an image to jpg with no modifications you can expect some pixels to differ.

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code and your result. Looks like they need to be aligned first.

Comment: @Reti43 what is the recommended image format?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do really. If it's strict pixel-by-pixel comparison (these means both photos are aligned, on the same scale/rotation/lightning/etc, jpg might cause problems. But for more clever algorithms, as the answer below has demonstrated, this may not be an issue.

Answer (score 5):

The problem you are having is that your images are not aligned before you do your difference xor. Here is one way to handle that using ORB feature matching in Python/OpenCV.

Input 1:

[image]

Input 2:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
 
MAX_FEATURES = 500
GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT = 0.15
  
def alignImages(im1, im2):

  # im2 is reference and im1 is to be warped to match im2
  # note: numbering is swapped in function
 
  # Convert images to grayscale
  im1Gray = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  im2Gray = cv2.cvtColor(im2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   
  # Detect ORB features and compute descriptors.
  orb = cv2.ORB_create(MAX_FEATURES)
  keypoints1, descriptors1 = orb.detectAndCompute(im1Gray, None)
  keypoints2, descriptors2 = orb.detectAndCompute(im2Gray, None)
   
  # Match features.
  matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create(cv2.DESCRIPTOR_MATCHER_BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING)
  matches = matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, None)
   
  # Sort matches by score
  matches.sort(key=lambda x: x.distance, reverse=False)
 
  # Remove not so good matches
  numGoodMatches = int(len(matches) * GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT)
  matches = matches[:numGoodMatches]
 
  # Draw top matches
  imMatches = cv2.drawMatches(im1, keypoints1, im2, keypoints2, matches, None)
  cv2.imwrite("circuit_matches.png", imMatches)
   
  # Extract location of good matches
  points1 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)
  points2 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)
 
  for i, match in enumerate(matches):
    points1[i, :] = keypoints1[match.queryIdx].pt
    points2[i, :] = keypoints2[match.trainIdx].pt
   
  # Find homography
  h, mask = cv2.findHomography(points1, points2, cv2.RANSAC)
 
  # Use homography
  height, width, channels = im2.shape
  im1Reg = cv2.warpPerspective(im1, h, (width, height))
   
  return im1Reg, h
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
   
  # Read reference image
  refFilename = "circuit1.jpg"
  print("Reading reference image : ", refFilename)
  imReference = cv2.imread(refFilename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
  hh, ww = imReference.shape[:2]
  
  # Read image to be aligned
  imFilename = "circuit2.jpg"
  print("Reading image to align : ", imFilename);  
  im = cv2.imread(imFilename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
   
  # Aligned image will be stored in imReg. 
  # The estimated homography will be stored in h. 
  imReg, h = alignImages(im, imReference)
   
  # Print estimated homography
  print("Estimated homography : \n",  h)
  
  # Convert images to HSV and get saturation channel
  refSat = cv2.cvtColor(imReference, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[:,:,1]
  imSat = cv2.cvtColor(imReg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[:,:,1]

  # Otsu threshold
  refThresh = cv2.threshold(refSat, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
  imThresh = cv2.threshold(imSat, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

  # apply morphology open and close
  kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7,7))
  refThresh = cv2.morphologyEx(refThresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
  refThresh = cv2.morphologyEx(refThresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1).astype(np.float64)
  imThresh = cv2.morphologyEx(imThresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1).astype(np.float64)
  imThresh = cv2.morphologyEx(imThresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)
  
  # get absolute difference between the two thresholded images
  diff = np.abs(cv2.add(imThresh,-refThresh))
  
  # apply morphology open to remove small regions caused by slight misalignment of the two images
  kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (12,12))
  diff_cleaned = cv2.morphologyEx(diff, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1).astype(np.uint8)

  # Filter using contour area and draw bounding boxes that do not touch the sides of the image
  cnts = cv2.findContours(diff_cleaned, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
  cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
  result = imReference.copy()
  for c in cnts:
      x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
      if x>0 and y>0 and x+w<ww-1 and y+h<hh-1:
        cv2.rectangle(result, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

  # save images
  cv2.imwrite('circuit2_aligned.jpg', imReg)
  cv2.imwrite('circuit_diff.png', diff_cleaned)
  cv2.imwrite('circuit_result.png', result)

 # show images
  cv2.imshow('reference', imReference)
  cv2.imshow('image', im)
  cv2.imshow('image_aligned', imReg)
  cv2.imshow('refThresh', refThresh)
  cv2.imshow('imThresh', imThresh)
  cv2.imshow('diff', diff)
  cv2.imshow('diff_cleaned', diff_cleaned)
  cv2.imshow('result', result)
  cv2.waitKey()
```

ORB Match Locations:

[image]

Image 2 aligned to Image 1:

[image]

Thresholded Difference:

[image]

Result showing difference regions:

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate. You are a life savior. My biggest problems were to filter away all the noises created by the white bars at the top and the 'brown tracks' that you have successfully identified them with the 3 red boxes.

I will look into your code and understand your method of doing it.

Comment: I did not align the image. That's the problem. Your answer works amazingly. Thank you for the help. I have also tried on other sample images, some were good and some are showing multiple false positive. I will look into it and see how i can twerk it

Comment: improvement: use Lowe's ratio test. that discards ambiguous matches.